# "git add" equivalent in svn?

Tags: svn, git

To commit some changes to a git repo I must add it to the staged state first. If I don't add a file to commit it will not go to the repo.

But in SVN, apparently, there is no such staging state. And every change I made to my working copy goes to the repo with next svn commit. How can I prevent some locally changed files get commited without reverting the changes?

Comment: It's interesting to see this question that way round, i.e. rather than being surprised that git has the "staging area" idea, someone asking for something similar in Subversion :)  There's a nice discussion of this in [a blog post by Elijah Newren](http://blogs.gnome.org/newren/2007/12/08/limbo-why-users-are-more-error-prone-with-git-than-other-vcses/)

Comment: argh I came here looking for the same feature.. heart broken that it's not a thing. staging area makes it easy not only to specify which files to commit, but also as a sort of local "save". I use it all the time when I've made good progress on a feature, and don't want to commit just yet, but want to continue to modify the same file, while always being able to revert to that staged version

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `svn commit` command takes optional filename parameters that limit the set of files to commit:

```
svn commit -m "my commit" file1.txt file2.txt
```

You can also use the ["changelist" feature](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.changelist.html) to group one or more files into a changelist, which can be submitted in one command. This is still slightly less flexible than Git, because you can't add just a portion of a single file (such as with `git add -p`).

Comment: I would do without the word "slightly" in "This is still slightly less flexible than Git"—to commit parts of files is exactly the feature I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can give specific filenames and directories to svn commit via something like:

```
svn commit myfile.c
```

which will only commit that one file.